# Sending a created website to somebody

Tags: javascript, html

I am just a beginner in HTML (and soon JS), and I was wondering, once my website is complete (an html file made in either Sublime or Notepad), how do I get that website to other people? If I wanted to make a website eventually with my online portfolio of videos and images, how would I get it out to people?

Comment: The website? Or the file? You can buy a domain and host your code there, or send the code by... anything! Email, GitHub (**preferred**), Google Drive. Contact GoDaddy, for example. But SO is not the place for that. If you have trouble with your code, then come here. :) For example: I have a site (let's say http://danispringer.com), I write HTML, and upload it to my website back-end. GitHub can be used to share the actual code, instead of the output. So I can put my actual code on GitHub, like http://github.com/danispringer

Comment: You can use git

Comment: Heck, if it's not too big, put it in a zip and email it to them. Then tell them to open your HTML file.

Comment: What @TyQ. said is true as well. In that case, make sure you include all needed code and keep the file structure correct, so everything works. This question will likely get closed as it's not about programming. But hey, you got your answer.

Comment: You need to read up on the basics of hosting a website. Hosting can be purchased through thirdparties like Bluehost or HostGator, etc... Check this beginner guide on hosting.
[http://www.webhostingsecretrevealed.net/web-hosting-beginner-guide/]

Answer (score 0):

Uploading website files are one of the very first steps users have to take in order to publish their creation on the Internet. This tutorial will provide a generalized example on how to upload a website using one of three basic tools:

> What you’ll need?

Before you begin this guide you’ll need the following:

- Access to the control panel of your hosting account
- Your website’s files (preferably compressed in a .zip or .tar.gz
  format archive)
- (Optional) An FTP client and FTP login details of your hosting
  account

> Option 1 – Upload Your Website via Hosting's File Manager

1. Navigate to your control panel’s Files category and open File
   Manager
2. After that, go to the public_html directory, which is the root
   directory of your domain (for example http://www.domainname.com/).
   Your files should be uploaded there. The directory may also be changed depending on what URL you want it to be accessed from. In case
   you want the content to show up on
   http://www.domainname.com/something/ your content would need to be
   located in public_html/something directory.
3. To start uploading, right-click with your mouse and select Upload
   Files option.
4. To unzip your archive, right-click it and press Extract.

Once the content is located in your desired location, you will be able to access it using any browser.

> Option 2 – Uploading Your Website via FTP

Some users prefer using an FTP client, such as **FileZilla**, **SmartFTP**, **CoreFTP**, or any other in order to upload their website. In this example, we will use Filezilla.

1. Firstly, you will need to get your FTP details.they
   are located in your control panel’s FTP Access section. If you are not sure what your FTP password is, you can easily reset it by pressing Change account password section.
2. Open FileZilla and input your FTP connection details into the fields
   at the top of the program, then click Quickconnect.
3. Once you are connected to the FTP server, use the file browser on
   the LEFT side of the program to find your website’s files on your computer. After you have found your website’s files, use the file the browser on the RIGHT side to open your public_html directory on the hosting server. Once you have done this, you can simply drag-and-drop files from left to right and they will be uploaded to the server.(OPTIONAL) Similarly, you can upload a compressed archive via FTP by dragging-and-dropping from left to right. You will also need to extract it via File Manager. Refer to the “Option 1 — Uploading your website via File Manager” part of the tutorial above for instructions on how to extract archives via File Manager.

> Option 3 – Uploading Your Website via cPanel’s File Manager

1. Click on the File Manager icon, located under the Files category.
2. Once inside the File Manager, open the public_html directory.
3. Click Upload after entering the public_html directory.
4. You can click “Select File” to select a singular file, or simply
   drag-and-drop your file to the outlined area.
5. Once the upload is complete, return to the File Manager and you will
   see the uploaded archive in your public_html directory. Right, click
   the archive and select Extract to extract the archive.
6. If you receive a prompt asking to specify the location the archive
   should be extracted to, make sure to specify /public_html.
7. The archive is now extracted, all files should now be located inside
   public_html. Navigate back to public_html and see if the files were moved successfully.
8. Your website should now be fully uploaded and accessible via your
   website’s URL. All that remains is to access your website and check if everything works correctly. Simply type in your domain name in
   your browser, such as http://www.domainname.com/, and check if your
   website works to your satisfaction

you have just learned how to upload a website. As you may see, you can upload a lot of files at once via an FTP program more easily, however, each file will be uploaded one-by-one. As a result, it may take a long time for each file to be uploaded separately, so it is still strongly advised to create a compressed archive of your files before uploading them.

On the other hand, the File manager is useful for uploading one or two files quickly, since you do not need a separate program for the File manager to work and can update your website on-the-fly, while working on other tasks inside your hosting control panel.